# Tomcat instances stucks

Tags: tomcat

We are having an web application which is hosted on UNIX server and where apache and tomcat instances are running.often the web page is not opening for search functionality is not working...to fix that we need to restart the apchae-tomcatctl instances..but when we are executing the command ./apache-tomcatctl status..it is showing as up.but the application page is not coming..we then stopped and start the service.. For permanent fix we are hoping to put alert on Apache and tomcat instances and want to receive mail when it gets stuck or stopped.so is there any possible way to do that??? Please need help on these.

Comment: Are you sure you have a single command to control both Apache and Tomcat?  That is very unusual.

Comment: I am using ./apache-tomcatctl status,which is showing me the tomcat status...so is there any way to fix these..

Comment: Where does `./apache-tomcatctl` come from? Did it come with your OS? Which OS is it? If so, how? If not, who wrote it? We can't guess how it works, Google doesn't find it.

Comment: This question doesn't belong on StackOverflow. It probably belongs on ServerFault, but I can't flag it for that (it's not a noption).